# Show Last Updated Time instead of Published Time

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime

I'm very new to Php. I want to show the Last Updated date instead of the Published time. Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'minimalistblogger_posted_on' ) ) :
    function minimalistblogger_posted_on() {
        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
        if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
            $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
        }

        $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
            esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_date() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
        );

        $posted_on = sprintf(
            esc_html_x( 'Posted on %s', 'post date', 'minimalistblogger' ),
            '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
        );

        $byline = sprintf(
            esc_html_x( 'by %s', 'post author', 'minimalistblogger' ),
            '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a></span>'
        );

        echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span><span class="byline"> ' . $byline . '</span>'; // WPCS: XSS OK.

    }
endif;
```

Comment: what framework do you use here?

Comment: `$timestring` would possibly show the updated date, but it's never used after beeing set.

Comment: it's on Wordpress. But on the post, it only shows "Posted on .... published date ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WordPress 6.2 (and maybe 6.*), you can simply use markup for the Date Block like this:

```
<!-- wp:post-date {"displayType":"modified"} /-->
```

This one includes the time as well as the date:

```
<!-- wp:post-date {"format":"M j, Y g:i A","displayType":"modified"} /-->
```

For example, I can paste either of these in the 2023 theme patterns/post-meta.php and they will render the last modified date.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I found it!

Just use the

> get_the_modified_time('F d, Y');
>
> $modifiedtime = get_the_modified_time('F d, Y'); $posted_on = sprintf(
>             esc_html_x( 'Last modified on %s', 'post date', 'minimalistblogger'
>   ),            '' .
>   $modifiedtime . ''        );

thank you :)